# What is the best way to handle removing elements from an array while iterating through it in Unreal Engine Blueprint?

Tags: blueprints, unreal-5

I'm trying to remove "Park" Area Controls from a Scene Actions array in Unreal Engine Blueprint. My current attempt doesn't work, and I'd appreciate help troubleshooting it.

Details:

- I have a Game Scene Ref object with an array of Scene Actions.
- Each Scene Action has an array of Area Controls.
- Each Area Control has an Area object with a Content Type property.
- I want to remove any Area Control where the Content Type is "Park" from the Scene Actions array.

My current blueprint does the following:

- Loops through Scene Actions.
- Loops through each Action's Area Controls.
- Checks if the Area Control's Area has a Content Type of "Park".
- If it does, directly removes the Area Control from the
  current array.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can remove elements of an array while iterating through an array.
But you can create a temporary list and instead add an element to it if the element should not be removed and do not add if you wish to remove it from the array.
At the end you can convert the list into an array.